# Supervisor using Meteor settings.json On Launch

Tags: meteor, supervisord

How to pass a `--settings` json file to meteor with supervisor?
If I run the meteor run command from the home command, everything is perfect:

```
meteor --settings settings.json
```

This is my current `conf.d` file:

```
[program:demo]
command=/usr/local/bin/meteor
directory=/home/username/demo
autostart=true
autorestart=true
environment=
    HOME="/home/username",
    METEOR_SETTINGS="/home/username/demo/settings.json"
stdout_logfile=/home/username/demo.log
stdout_logfiel_maxbytes=50MB
user=username
```

which gives the following error:

```
Errors prevented isopacket load:

While loading isopacket `constraint-solver`:
packages/meteor.js:59:11: METEOR_SETTINGS are not valid JSON:
/home/username/demo/settings.json
at packages/meteor.js:59:11
at packages/meteor.js:80:4
at packages/meteor.js:1380:3
```

**settings.json**

```
{
  "private": {
    "init_admin": {
      "userName": "admin",
      "email": "admin@example.com",
      "password": "test123"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your settings file (with any sensitive info in it removed) so we can see that it is valid JSON?

Comment: done. but as I said, running it manually works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised no one has answered this already. I found your question on google when trying to figure out how to put the settings.json file into METEOR_SETTINGS and avoid syntax errors in the supervisor config.

Because to answer your question, **METEOR_SETTINGS environment variable must contain JSON. So it must contain the JSON data of settings.json, not the filename or path**.

Which is kinda dumb because you're putting JSON data into an environment variable. So basically METEOR_SETTINGS="$(cat settings.json|tr -d '\n')" but doing this causes problems with supervisord since this syntax apparently is not supported.

```
"error: <class 'xmlrpclib.Fault'>, <Fault 92: 'CANT_REREAD: Unexpected end of key/value pairs'>: file: /usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py line: 794"]
```

My permanent solution was to wrap the node command with a shell script so that I could properly set the METEOR_SETTINGS variable in bash instead of supervisord.

So remove METEOR_SETTINGS from your environment in supervisord. (Here is an example from my Ansible so that's why values are enclosed by brackets)

```
[program:pwfrank]                                                                                                                            
directory={{pwfrank_home}}/build/bundle                                                                                                      
command={{pwfrank_home}}/start_node.sh 
environment=                                                                                                                                 
  HOME="{{pwfrank_home}}",                                                                                                                   
  MONGO_URL="{{pwfrank_mongo_url}}",                                                                                                         
  PORT="{{pwfrank_listenport}}",                                                                                                             
  ROOT_URL="{{pwfrank_baseurl}}"
```

And create a shell script like this for example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export METEOR_SETTINGS="$(cat {{pwfrank_home}}/pwfrank/{{pwfrank_settings_file}} | tr -d '\n')"                                              

/usr/local/bin/meteor node main.js
```

This worked for me but I'm moving away from supervisor and into systemd instead because systemd has environment files so I won't have to use shell scripts to wrap node.

Edit for future googlers: I ended up realizing that systemd works fine as long as you put the json data beteween single quote marks. Personally I accomplish this with ansible, extracting the JSON data with the cat|tr command I mentioned above, putting it into an ansible fact and then using the fact in the template of my EnvironmentFile for the Meteor service unit in systemd.